# Firestore add document listener in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to ADD listener for getting new data in Firestore.
I'm using this code. It it working perfect when a new document is added.
But the problem with this code is, when the screen is loaded this code first time fetch all the data. But I did not want this. I just want to get new added document data in Firetore instead of getting all thee list first time Here is the code ->

```
   firestore
        .orderBy('created', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((result) {
          result.docChanges.forEach((res) {
             if (res.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {


         }
       }
```